# Stack Smashed upon function return

Tags: assembly, kernel, x86-64

I am trying to boot a custom kernel in QEMU. There is a simple function in this kernel called `ast_pending` ([source](https://github.com/Andromeda-OS/Kernel/blob/master/osfmk/i386/cpu.c#L230-L234)). The function is compiled into the following assembler:

```
pushq   %rbp
movq    %rsp, %rbp
movq    %gs:0x0, %rax
addq    $0x58, %rax
popq    %rbp
retq
```

Somehow, when the `ret` instruction is executed, it tries to return to a garbage function address; `rbp` is also trashed. Interestingly, it is the same address, every time I run it. I suspect corruption of the stack or return address. Is there anything in this function that could have caused stack/`rbp` corruption? (Unfortunately, I cannot yet determine where the caller is, due to the stack smashing, so I cannot post the call-site code.)

Comment: Did you get my email about the timer interrupt?

Comment: @Jester: Yes, I did. Thank you very much; it was just what I needed! This is a different issue.